# USBview encountering error

Tags: usb, usbview

I am having problems using the USB ports on my Acer Aspire one. I have download the USBview app and when open it I get the following error:

```
Invalid desktop entry file: /usr/share/applications/usbview.desktop
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though `USBView` installs the desktop file for Ubuntu 17.10 running Wayland as it tries to run a command `sudo-to-root` that is not compatible with Ubuntu 16.04.

Try installing `gksu` for GTK sudo.

```
sudo apt install gksu
```

Then copy and paste the following line to update the Desktop File:

```
sudo bash -c 'sed -i "s/sudo-to-root -X -c/gksudo/" /usr/share/applications/usbview.desktop'
```

Hope this helps!